Change the NPM Install Command in New Firebase AppHosting
I need help customising the new Firebase AppHosting build process. Because Firebase AppHosting is new, there is very little technical information on customisations, edge-cases, issues that I can relate to the issue I am having.
I am trying to change the default rollout npm install command npm ci --quiet to an install command that suits our Angular application but I am not sure how to do this.
Example rollout build log
I have setup a apphosting.yaml file but that is it so far.
But if anyone can point me in the right direction or any help on this is greatly appreciated.
